# Create remote directory using fabric.operations.put()

Tags: python, sftp, fabric

I need to put some files onto a remote sftp server, creating a new directory to put them in.  Is there a way to do this using fabric?  Fabric.operations.put() doesn't look like it can handle creating the new directory on the remote side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run `mkdir` before calling [`put()`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.put):

```
run('mkdir -p /path/to/dir/')

put('/local/path/to/myfile', '/path/to/dir/')
```

[`-p` flag](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mkdir) handles creating nested directories, see:

> -p, --parents
>
> no error if existing, make parent directories as needed

---

Update (for sftp-only access).

Using [`SFTP.mkdir()`](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/sftp.py#L105):

```
from contextlib import closing
from fabric.sftp import SFTP

ftp = SFTP(env.host_string)
with closing(ftp) as ftp:
    ftp.mkdir('/path/to/dir/', use_sudo=False)

put('/local/path/to/myfile', '/path/to/dir/')
```